# vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR not returning

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm trying to implement Vulkan to my game but I'm stuck at `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR` because the function not returning it just crash inside function.

I'm sure both `VkPhysicalDevice` and `VkSurfaceKHR` are initialized as they are used in other that works as expected.

I'm running Linux on X11 and I've an Intel chip and discrete Nvidia card. the function works fine when it getting surfaceCapabilities from Intel device but it crashes when it's Nvidia device.

Furthermore the function not returning any error, it even not returning zero.

#### EDIT

There is also no validation error.

Here a sample that illustrate the porblem :

- [GameEngine.h](https://pastebin.com/CqE1PEJ6)
- [GameEngine.cpp](https://pastebin.com/NV1RyHqa)
- [CMakeLists.txt](https://pastebin.com/J30kLJdV)

Comment: @AlanBirtles  I've updated my question on this new post because the older one got closed.

Comment: @SaschaWillems I've updated my question on this new post because the older one got closed.

Comment: I've runned vkcube demo and it's also crashing when using the Nvidia gpu. So I think it's a driver issue. I'm waiting for driver update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my problem is solved, it was related to my setup. I'm running a linux laptop and the support for hybrid graphics is poor. But my program is working !!